# How to find line number with specific string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hacked together some code that loops through hundreds of text files and scans each for a specific string.  It works fine, but I want to modify it to find lines that ONLY contain a line-feed character, and subtract these out.  Here is an example.

```
1 ISSUE
2 ID_DES
3 SOURCE
4 ID_CO
5 ID_NAME
6 END-OF-FIELDS
7
8 
9 START-OF-DATA
```

Code:

```
import os

search_path = 'C:\\my_path\\'
file_type = '.txt'
search_str = 'START-OF-DATA'

# Append a directory separator if not already present
if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\")):
    search_path = search_path + "/"

# If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
if not os.path.exists(search_path):
    search_path = "."

# Repeat for each file in the directory
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):

    # Apply file type filter
    if fname.endswith(file_type):

        # Open file for reading
        fo = open(search_path + fname)

        # Read the first line from the file
        line = fo.readline()

        # Initialize counter for line number
        line_no = 1

        # Loop until EOF
        while line != '':
            # Search for string in line
            index = line.find(search_str)
            if (index != -1):
                print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")

            # Read next line
            line = fo.readline()

            # Increment line counter
            line_no += 1
        # Close the files
        fo.close()

print('DONE!!')
```

As the code is now, I will get a 9, but I want to see 7, because I am subtracting out 2 rows with nothing but line-feed characters.  I thought it was something like this: `if not line.split():`

However, that doesn't seem to work for me.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `line = fo.readline().strip("\n\r")` (in both places)?

Comment: grep already does this. Learning project? Also, probably could skip the file finding and just post the function to check one file, here (keep it relevant to the question, lose the rest) It looks like you have a bad loop condition -- are you really completely done with that file if you see a blank line?

Comment: `if (len(line) ~= 2 or line[0]~='\n' or line[1]~='\r'): line_no+=1`

Comment: @DDS, I am getting 'invalid syntax' message.

Comment: @CristiFati, it didn't work. If I replace both 'line = fo.readline()' it seems to skip the whole process and just print 'Done!!'.  If I replace the first 'line = fo.readline()' I get the same result I had initially.

Comment: Sorry: not equal should be !=. `if (len(line) != 2 or line[0]!='\r or line[1]!='\n'): line_no+=1` (windows EOL is CRLF not LFCR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import os

search_path = r'C:\my_path'
file_type = '.txt'
search_str = 'START-OF-DATA'

# If path does not exist, set search path to current directory.
if not os.path.exists(search_path):
    search_path = "."

for fname in os.listdir(search_path):
    if os.path.splitext(fname)[1] == file_type:
        line_no = 1
        with open(os.path.join(search_path, fname)) as fo:
            for line in (line.rstrip() for line in fo):
                index = line.find(search_str)
                if index != -1:
                    print("{}[{},{}] {}".format(fname, line_no, index, line))
                if line:  # Non-empty line?
                    line_no += 1

print('DONE!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code

```
with open(filename) as file: 
    linenumber = 0
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            handle_line (linenumber, line)
            linenumber += 1
```

Let python iterate over the lines in the file, it's good at that. If you want to count the line numbers differently, then that's easy, just maintain your own line number.

Here, I demonstrate removing all whitespace from the beginning and end, then seeing if anything is left. If so then count and handle that line. This may be more robust than looking for some OS specific encodings of a line.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but all of these suggestions are giving me the exact same results as I had initially.

Comment: This actually gives me a 7 for your START-OF-DATA line. Unless we have a misunderstanding -- are the line numbers actually physically printed in the file? If the line is NOT in fact just a blank line, that check won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing those line numbers are actually in the data file. Then I misunderstood originally. This is probably going to be the time to use regular expressions.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<linenumber>\d+) (?P<content>.*)')
with open(filename) as file:
    # maintain your own custom line number
    my_linenumber = 1

    # let python iterate through the lines
    for line in file.readlines():

        # use the regular expressions module to parse the data
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if match and 2==len(match.groups()):
            file_linenumber = match.groups()[0]
            content = match.groups()[1]

            # remove whitespace and see if anything is left
            if content.strip():
                print (my_linenumber, content)
                my_linenumber += 1
```

Notice that there is an extra space on line 8, so it's not just \r\n